# Prove, by induction, the recurrence $T\left(n\right)\:=\:2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+kn\leqslant cn\log\left(n\right)\;$ for some $c>0$.

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

> Prove, by induction, the recurrence $T\left(n\right)\:=\:2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+kn\leqslant cn\log\left(n\right)\;$ for some $c>0$.

My notes say that the base-case holds implicitly for this and the prove can directly start from the inductive-step. Can someone explain why we don't need to mention the base case? Thanks.

Additional context:

[image]